# Module HMRClient is not a registered callable module (calling setup)

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error in react-native. This error came when I installed [This self developed and published package.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-mathjax)

```
Module HMRClient is not a registered callable module (calling setup)
```

Same code is working on my app when using it without NPM module.

Comment: Just open "Dev Settings" in your app and set "JS Dev Mode to true". It works for me.

Comment: App crashes when I am trying to click on settings. By the way JS Dev mode is true already